# Apt-get stuck wiating for a response

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade

I launched the command `apt full-upgrade` on a SSH connection, And than my session has timedout and the apt is still hanging here (term.log) :

```
*** sudoers (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

So I need to respond So it can continue.

I'm on ***ubuntu 14.04***

What should I do ?

**EDIT**

When I launch `apt-get autoclean` I get :

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

**EDIT 2** :

```
lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/124/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
dpkg    3409 root    3uW  REG    9,1        0 791425 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

**Edit 3** 
output `pstree -psa 3409` :

```
init,1
  └─sudo,26185 apt full-upgrade
      └─apt,26186 full-upgrade
          └─dpkg,3409 --status-fd 84 --configure perl:amd64 perl-modules:all libperl5.18:amd64 libc-dev-bin:amd64 linux-libc-dev:amd64 libc6-dev:amd64 libc6-dbg:amd64 libapt-inst1.5:amd64 libexpat1:amd64 libexpat1-dev:amd64 ...
```

Comment: So you ran `apt-get` over SSH, but without using screen or tmux and the connection was lost?

Comment: yeah, that's about it

Comment: Add the output of `pstree -psa 3409` please

Comment: @muru See my 3rd edit

Comment: Since it looks there are no child processes, you can try something like `echo N | sudo tee /proc/3409/fd/0` to send something to dpkg's input. And `tail -f /proc/3409/fd/1` to see what it outputs after that.

Comment: The first command just printed N and the second nothing showed

Comment: And `tail -f /proc/3409/fd/2`?

Comment: nothing also....

Answer (score 0):

For futur reference, I've resolved this with stopping dpkg with :

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

then :

```
apt-get update
```

I got a message like dpkg was stopped, do you want to resume ?, I typed yes and all worked fine.